# Python : Add a column into a dataframe with different length repeating the added column till fill the dataframe length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hos I could a do this one:

Df1:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | AA |
| 02 | AB |
| 03 | AC |
| 05 | AD |

Df2:

| C |
| --- |
| 11 |
| 12 |

Dataframe looking for:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | AA | 11 |
| 02 | AB | 12 |
| 03 | AC | 11 |
| 05 | AD | 12 |

How could I reach this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)** to repeat the elements of column `C`:

```
m, n = len(df1), len(df2)
df1['C'] = np.tile(df2['C'], int(np.ceil(m / n)))[:m]
```

Result:

```
   A   B   C
0  1  AA  11
1  2  AB  12
2  3  AC  11
3  5  AD  12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `concat` :

```
   >>> pd.concat([df1,df2.append(df2).reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)

       A   B     C
    0  1  AA  11.0
    1  2  AB  12.0
    2  3  AC  11.0
    3  5  AD  12.0
```